# Upgrading from Ubuntu 32 bit to 64 bit with software raid

Tags: upgrade, 64-bit, raid5

I'm currently running Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit. I'd like to move to 64 bit and everything I've read has stated that I should probably completely reinstall to do so. I have my OS on a 1GB hard drive and then I have a 10TB software RAID mounted to a separate folder.

My question is, if I completely reinstall Ubuntu, will I lose my software RAID, or will the new installation recognize the software RAID once I remount it, with all of my data intact?

Comment: I've posted my removed comment as an answer so you can mark it as the accepted answer ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sofware RAID is in a different partition than Ubuntu is, you won't lose any of that data.